# How Can I extract the compete hash of parameters sent along with controler call in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I can extract one by one like params[:id] but how to extract all of them like params[:all] or parameters['all'].

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"aom7v66e309yjkd2x0aq", "video_type"=>"trailer"}
```

Comment: what's your expected output for the given example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails parameters are instances of [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), a subclass of [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html).

```
params.class
# => HashWithIndifferentAccess
params.is_a? Hash
# => true
```

You can get the entire `Hash` with `params`:

```
params
# => {"id"=>"aom7v66e309yjkd2x0aq", "video_type"=>"trailer"}
```

Or with [`#to_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#method-i-to_hash) if you need a plain `Hash`:

```
params.to_hash
# => {"id"=>"aom7v66e309yjkd2x0aq", "video_type"=>"trailer"}
params.to_hash.class
# => Hash
```

The keys with [`#keys`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys):

```
params.keys
# => ["id", "video_type"]
```

And the values with [`#values`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
params.values
# => ["aom7v66e309yjkd2x0aq", "trailer"]
```

To extract specific keys, you can use [`#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
params = {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
params.slice("a", "c")
# => {"a"=>1, "c"=>3}
```

Or its counterpart [`#except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except):

```
params = {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
params.except("b")
# => {"a"=>1, "c"=>3}
```